# Galaxy S20 does not call onSensorChanged method but it works on another device

Tags: java, android, samsung-mobile

I started developing a little app and I have some weird issues with my Galaxy S20. The stepcounter just doesn't work. It's getting registered but the onSensorChanged method is not called for whatever reason. I tried the same code on an old smartphone and there were no issues at all. Do you guys have any idea what could be the cause? Here's my code:

```
public class Userprofile extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {
    Sensor stepSensor;
    SensorManager sManager;
    TextView stepText;
    boolean running = false;
    private int steps = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_userprofile);
        sManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        stepText = findViewById(R.id.stepcounter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        running = true;
        stepSensor = sManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);

        if(stepSensor == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Sensor detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            sManager.registerListener(this, stepSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Listener registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        running = false;
        sManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        sManager.unregisterListener(this, stepSensor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if(running) {
            stepText.setText((String.valueOf(event.values[0])));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }
}
```